# Signing pdf with Okular

Tags: pdf, certificates, okular, signature

I saw that in Okular we can now digitally sign a document.

I would like to know the steps from scratch to make this work. At the moment Okular tells me "There are no available signing certificates".

Comment: A starting point is to look here here: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/okular/okular/signatures.html.

Comment: @Bruni That link only tells you how to set a certificate store, but not how to actually obtain or create certificates, which is the real hard part. There are instructions [here](https://reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/rclase/help_with_signing_a_pdf/hnxmc09/) for creating a self-signed certificate, but as the person there points out [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/rclase/help_with_signing_a_pdf/hnxr5sv/), such a certificate is meaningless. A real certificate authority providing means for verifying the signature is needed for any of this to be worthwhile.

Comment: @frabjous well, buying a certificate is kind of out of the scope of this site and would tend to become advertising for a specific certification authority. Also, if you buy a certificate you get instructions for that part.

Comment: This seems to work: https://gregbur.me/2022/04/28/deep-dive-digitally-signing-pdfs-with-okular/

Comment: See some issues here https://www.mail-archive.com/okular-devel@kde.org/msg38946.html and https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452095